# How to recreate this type of sound (Rave Stabs)

Tags: sound-design

How to recreate sounds like this -
[Rave Hardcore Stabs](http://www.freesound.org/people/wa11one/sounds/217891/)

Maybe this is a unique chorus (what synth (Alpha Juno?)) or this is special chords.

Need your help!

Comment: If you can expand on your question with more of a description of the sound (just in case the link goes dead) it would improve the question greatly.

Comment: @aj-henderson Please check link again, I can access a file from different browsers! Thank you! It ' s like PWM detuned squares and chorus. I want to try to reproduce this.

Comment: just to clarify, I wasn't saying the link is dead. In general, we want questions on SE to be useful to others with similar problems in the future.  Links aren't guaranteed to stay valid in the future, so it is preferred that a brief description of the link be provided whenever using a link as an example in a question or an answer.  It also makes questions easier to search.  Hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

If the sound you're asking about is similar to [this one](http://www.freesound.org/people/Kasatchok/sounds/165555/), then it is basically a distorted trance pluck. It can be recreated in any subtractive synth.
Here's a quick a dirty guide how to make it:

1. Set waveform to Sawtooth.
2. Set voices to 8 or so.
3. Detune the voices a bit (that may be called "Spread" or "Detune" or similar).
4. If you have a 2nd oscillator, then repeat steps 1-3 but raise it by 19 semitones (1 octave and then 5th). If that sounds too weird, try 7 semitones (5th) or 12 (octave).

That will give you a supersaw sound. There are also tons on tutorials on Youtube on how to create a supersaw sound.

Now tweak the amplitude envelope. Set it to quick Attack, quick Decay, Sustain to about half of maximum amplitude, quick Release with a short tail. That will give you a pluck sound.

Now add a distortion effect, something like Amp Tube is a good choice, and crank up the Drive knob until you like what you hear.

Load a Sawtooth waveform into both oscillators, increase the number of voices to eight on both and raise one of the oscillators one octave.

Note that in the sound I chose an example, distortion drive is automated. You can clearly hear the sound becoming more distorted with time.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is "page not found". But classic rave Stabs are made by layering the korg M1 housepiano preset with detuned saw waves(often called supersaw).

Comment: Hm. Please try again. I know about m1 sounds, but this sounds different, its like pwm'd squares, and unique dirty 'chorus' :-), I want to learn how to reproduce this. Thank you.